# Quotient Spaces

Tags: general-topology

Find a pair of topological spaces $X$ and $Y$ with $G$ acting on them such that $X/G \cong Y/ G$ while $X$ is not homeomorphic to $Y$.  I know $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}_2$ and $[0,1)/\mathbb{Z}_2$ is such a pair, but I wonder if there are others.

Comment: Any pair $X,Y$ with $Y=X/G$ and $G$ acting on $Y$ trivially, is an example. As long as $X$ is not homeomorphic to $Y$. For example, $S^2/\{x\mapsto-x\}$ and $\Bbb RP^2$.